# Disable Calendar Location Correction in Yosemite

Tags: macos, calendar, ical

In Yosemite, the Calendar application will automatically clean up addresses entered in the Location field of a calendar entry. Unfortunately, it does so badly. For example, an entry for `Brasserie Zedel, 20 Sherwood Street W1F 7ED` gets corrected to `20 Sherwood Street London England W1F 7ED United Kingdom`, adding some information that's not needed (London, England and United Kingdom are all pretty much implicit) but deleting the crucial item, the name of the restaurant. Is it possible to disable this flawed autocorrection? Disabling general text autocorrection does not do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a known issue without a switch yet. Check out this forum https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6634705

> Send Apple feedback. They won't answer, but at least will know there
>   is a problem. If enough people send feedback, it may get the problem
>   solved sooner.